# Cannot run Add-Migration in Visual Studio 2022, EF6 Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2022

I try add-Migration on Visual Studio 2022, EntityFramework 6 but it doesn't work. I get an error

```
PM> EntityFramework\Add-Migration -ConfigurationTypeName STS.Core.Migrations.Configuration "AddCheckChanges"
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetProjectTypes(Project project, Int32 shellVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.IsWebSiteProject(Project project)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetTargetDir(Project project)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName, Boolean useContextWorkingDirectory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
```

I need help about it. Thanks so much

Comment: Look at the ConfigureServices method, you might be missing dependency. You can look at DataContext constructor and Startup.ConfigureServices code to get some understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who do have this problem using Visual Studio 2022: Switch back to Visual Studio 2019, as it doesn't work yet in the 2022 version when you are using an older Entity Framework version.

On the [relevant issue file on the Entity Framework 6 GitHub repository](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/1916),project member ajcvickers [commented on 2021-11-18](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/1916#issuecomment-972609832) :

```
[...] EF 6.2 doesn't work. You will need to update to EF 6.4.4. We have so far been unable to reproduce this with EF 6.4.4.
```

While numerous users have reported upgrading to EF 6.4.4 resolves their problem, the issue is still open, as there are users who can't downgrade to Visual Studio 2019 or upgrade Entity Framework, as those changes could break pipelines.